# Why does single line swap, a,b = b,a work in Python?

Tags: python, swap

I want to confidently use the Python idiom of swaping 2 values, `a,b = b,a` but I am not sure what is actually going on with this code. My guess is that, in memory, python creates a tuple containing b and a like (b,a) and then it changes a to point to the first element of the tuple and b to point to the second element.

Comment: In terms of language semantics, yeah. In terms of implementation details, CPython optimizes it a bit, but that mostly doesn't matter.

Comment: You could look at `dis.dis('a,b = b,a')`

Comment: Sometimes closing a question as a duplicate seems like a criticism. In this case, I was at first planning to answer it myself but then realized that I couldn't write something nearly as informative as Martijn Pieters' answer of the other question.

Comment: That's the right thing to do, Thanks @JohnColeman!